# Multiline select in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

In [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text), if I perform a find for an occurrence of a particular word, not only is this occurrence found, but it is also selected and has the cursor at the end of each occurrence so that pushing the right arrow key the cursor will move the cursor to the beginning of each occurrence simultaneously so that I can perform whatever operation I wish on all the selections. Does Notepad++ have something similar to this feature?

I know that I can multi-line select by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse click, but is there an automated way of doing this in Notepad++?

Comment: "Replace All" could be one option. And recording a simple macro would be another.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're describing is essentially a pretty version of "replace all", which Notepad++ and any decent text editor will have. I'm not aware of Notepad++ having the feature *exactly* as you describe it, so I'd just do a "Replace All". (btw, I'm using N++ version 5.8.7)